# dplyr: mutate() and mutate_if()

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to change all NAs in columns to 0.
I can do it with `mutate()`, but not with `mutate_if()`.

This works:

```
> test <- tibble(Q3.2 = c(1,2, NA, NA, 3),
                             Q8.2 = c(2, NA, 1, NA, 4))

> test %>% select_("Q3.2", "Q8.2") %>%
    mutate(Q3.2 = ifelse(is.na(Q3.2), 0, Q3.2),
           Q8.2 = ifelse(is.na(Q8.2), 0, Q8.2))
```

But this doesn't:

```
> test %>% select_("Q3.2", "Q8.2") %>%
+     mutate_if(is.na(.), 0, .)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'p' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR:

```
library(tidyr)
replace_na(list(Q3.2 = 0, Q8.2 = 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Axeman.

This was my first-ever answer on SO! I used SO extensively over the past year and taught myself R from absolute scratch, enough to build a commercial (prototype) DB app that does monthly reporting & analysis on a a very large group of disparate source files. (I'm not a programmer by either training or experience.)

Next time I answer I'll know that it's more helpful if I include the package. I really owe this community a lot.

Answer (score 9):

That is not what `mutate_if` does. It predicates on columns not rows, and therefore does not work the same as the `ifelse` within `mutate`. To replace all `NA`s with `0`s in numeric columns, try e.g.:

```
test %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

Or

```
test %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, coalesce, ... = 0)
```